# Get columns with distinct value counts greater than a specified value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Imagine the following Python Pandas Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo'], \
                   'A' : ['property1', 'property1', 'property2'], \
                   'B' : ['test', 'test', 'test'] })
from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))

+----+-----------+------+------+
|    | A         | B    | id   |
|----+-----------+------+------|
|  0 | property1 | test | foo  |
|  1 | property1 | test | bar  |
|  2 | property2 | test | foo  |
+----+-----------+------+------+
```

Here you can see that for the id **"foo"** column B has only one unique (distinct) value, which is **test**. But for column A it has two distinct values **property1** and **property2**. For the id **"bar"** both columns have only one distinct value.

What I'm looking for is code that gives me the name of those columns where the count is larger than 1 if **grouped by id**. So the result should be the name of column A since is hold non-distinct values.

```
df.groupby(['id'])
```

I only know how to get the ID's for which the count (occurance) is larger than 1. But it's not what I'm ultimately looking for.

```
df['id'].value_counts().reset_index(name="count").query("count > 1")["id"]
```

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: could you post your desired data set?

Comment: No, since it's confidential. Therefore I added that little demo-data.

Comment: i mean your desired data set based on your sample input data set...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
#filter column of interest
a = (df.groupby(['id'])['A','B'].nunique() > 1).any()

print (a)
A     True
B    False
dtype: bool

#if need test all columns without id
a = (df.set_index('id').groupby('id').nunique() > 1).any()
print (a)
A     True
B    False
dtype: bool
```

Last filter:

```
b = a.index[a]
print (b)
Index(['A'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: The second code snippet is what I was thinking too. But I'm not looking for the values, but for the column name that holds those values. This is because the original data set has like 32 columns.

Comment: Nice, works great. I used the code for checking all columns but without setting the index.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get the iindexing part. It works though.

Comment: @SourabhMaity - it filter index of `a` Series by values of boolean - so after `a.index[a]` get index only for True values.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're looking for:

```
g = df.groupby('id')['A', 'B'].nunique()
g

     A  B
id       
bar  1  1
foo  2  1
```

To get the relevant columns, just index into `df.columns`:

```
df.columns[(g > 1).any()]
Index(['A'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: this is what I thought :-)

Comment: And how would you then filter that dataframe in order to get the column name "A" that is the only column having values larger than 1.

Comment: @Matthias `df.columns.difference(['id'])[(df.groupby('id')['A', 'B'].nunique() > 1).any()]` --> gives `A`

Comment: Why do you need difference when you can do `df.columns[(df.groupby('id').nunique()>1).any()]`

Comment: @Bharath df.columns includes id while the indexer doesn’t.

Comment: I agree but I thought since we are using groupby, `id` will always have false values since no duplicates .

Comment: @Bharath ah I understand what you mean. Yeah that would simplify things! Feel free to edit my answer (I’m on my phone now)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [98]: df.columns.drop('id')[(df.groupby('id')[df.columns.drop('id')].nunique() > 1).any()]
Out[98]: Index(['A'], dtype='object')
```

---

```
In [31]: df[['A','B']].columns[df.groupby(['id'])['A','B'].apply(lambda x: x.nunique().gt(1)).any()]
Out[31]: Index(['A'], dtype='object')
```

Explanation:

```
In [32]: df.groupby(['id'])['A','B'].apply(lambda x: x.nunique().gt(1))
Out[32]:
         A      B
id
bar  False  False
foo   True  False

In [33]: df.groupby(['id'])['A','B'].apply(lambda x: x.nunique().gt(1)).any()
Out[33]:
A     True
B    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Couldnt find the method .gt but used > 1 instead. Anyway, is there a way to get this code without using the column names A and B and a list of all columns instead since the original data has lots of columns that I need to test.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way

```
pd.crosstab(df.id,[df.A,df.B],margins =True)
Out[206]: 
A   property1 property2 All
B        test      test    
id                         
bar         1         0   1
foo         1         1   2
All         2         1   3
```

Or something like

```
[x if df.groupby(['id',x]).ngroup().max()>1 else np.nan for x in df.columns]
Out[233]: ['A', nan, nan]
```

Comment: Though you still need the column names from there.